# Как вызвать функцию объекта, если имя объекта и имя функции хранятся в переменной?

Tags: javascript, node.js, переменные

Как вызвать функцию объекта, если имя объекта и имя функции хранятся в переменной?

```
let users = {
  go: function() {
    // это нужно вызвать
  }
};

let name = "users.go"; // с помощью этой переменной
```

Comment: самый простой способ - `eval(name)()`

Comment: @mymedia оставьте, пожалуйста, ответ

Answer (score 0):

Функция вызывается командой users.go().

eval выполняет код заданный строкой.

значит добавляем () к вашей переменной и вызываем или сразу добавляйте скобки let name="users.go()".

```js
let users = {
  go: function() {
    // это нужно вызвать
    alert("test");
  }
};

let name = "users.go";
//функция вызывается командой users.go()
//eval выполняет код заданный строкой
//значит добавляем () и вызываем или пишите let name="users.go()"
eval(name+"()");
```